# Set the zoom for MKMapCamera and MKUserTrackingMode to be equal in a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapcamera, mkusertrackingmode

I'm using both `MKUserTrackingMode` and `MKMapCamera` in the same ViewController to be able to track the user when they're navigating and to rotate the camera accordingly as the user travels along their route. `MKUserTrackingMode` zooms into a certain level, about 4,700 meters above the current location (using the iPhone 6 simulator) and `MKMapCamera` makes you specificy the eyeAltitude. Is there a way to make the `MKMapCamera` zoom level equal to the `MKUserTrackingMode` so that it doesn't first zoom to satisfy the `MKMapCamera` parameter then readjust to accompany the `MKUserTrackingMode` function?

`MKMapCamera` is in `convenience init` and `MKUserTrackingMode` is in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: hi @Pablo Picasso did you come up with a solution?